# PHP Curl & HTTPS not working

Tags: php, curl, https

So im using PHP and Curl trying to download a https weburl (from https://www.g2crowd.com) but its not working, here is the code i have so far one simple curl and the other more advanced curl , both are not working sadl. :(

```
// connect via SSL, but don't check cert
$ch=curl_init('https://www.g2crowd.com');
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, "cacert.pem");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);  

$content = curl_exec($ch);

echo $content; // show target page
$ckfile = tempnam ("/tmp", 'cookiename');

$url='https://www.g2crowd.com/';
//$url='https://www.google.com';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $ckfile );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $ckfile ); 

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$headers = [
'Host: www.g2crowd.com',
'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:43.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/43.0',
'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5',
'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate'    
];
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, 'C:\Users\ivan\Downloads\cacert.pem');

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, "https://www.g2crowd.com/users/c190d528-ab02-4cb5-8467-9362ceaec290");

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

$server_output = curl_exec ($ch);
if(curl_error($ch))
{
    echo curl_error($ch);
}
else {
    echo 'eureka!';
}

curl_close ($ch);
```

I tried to capture curl error so heres what the error is :

1407742E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version

Please help im really at my wits end!

THank you !!

Comment: Where (and to what) is `$i` set? (See line 18.)

Comment: Hey cHao good point !  Thats a debugging leftover when i tried to loop through various ssl protocols , but even then when i set it or delete that parameter - it still returns an error.

Answer (score 1):

Your `openssl` program is out of date.  I've also seen this on the OSX version native.  If you are on a Mac you will need to download a different `openssl`.  Or, opening the SSL with 0 means you opened without SSL.

Comment: Forbes thank you so much. I m using Zend Studio 13 IDE php debugger inside of Zend Studio, on a Windows 7 machine. So is this OpenSSL a program i need to install on windows or modify php.ini or something else?  I also have Wamp installed , should i try running the script on Wamp local php server?

Answer (score 0):

This should solve your problem:

```
$url='https://www.g2crowd.com/';

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, TRUE );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0 );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE );

$server_output = curl_exec( $ch );

curl_close( $ch );
```

If that does not work, try:

```
$url='https://www.g2crowd.com/';
$server_output = file_get_contents( $url );
```

Comment: Thanx for help Ben!  It may be just my PHP debugger but its not working , i assume you tried it and it worked for you ?  Let me know please if you tested it and it worked.

Comment: @IvanSimic The problem is almost certainly with the way you have PHP (or at least its SSL libraries) setup up. But that’s hard to fix remotely. Generally the curl option I gave cures a lot of ills. Try the second option I provided. It may do the trick.

Comment: Solved i tried it on Wamp server and got a different curl error this time: "check ssl certificate" so googled for solution , tried on wamp server and it worked.
Adding this code solved it: curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, 'C:\Users\ivan\Downloads\cacert.pem');

Comment: @IvanSimic Great!

Comment: hello,it results empty with your curl solutions,file_get_contents results Something goes wrong